# Skip SQS messages while consuming a queue

Tags: go, websocket, message-queue, amazon-sqs, event-driven

I have a message producer, sending messages like `{"user_id": 1, "message": "Ciao"}` to a SQS queue.

I have three instances of a Websocket API, their names being A, B and C.

Let's say five users connect to that API, their IDs being 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

Each user connects to the API and my balancer (sticky ofc) makes the clients connect to the API this way:

```
A: 1, 3
B: 5
C: 2, 4
```

Now, the Websocket API is the consumer of the SQS queue mentioned above.

When I enqueue a message for user 1, any consumer could dequeue it first, let's say C does.

Instance `C` can't do anything with messages for user_id 1. `A` does hold the actual connection to that user.

In my mind, this would work like: any message will be received by all of the three API instances.

- C will read it, and leave it in the queue
- B will read it, and leave it in the queue
- A will read it, process it and remove it from the queue

My question is:

**Is the above workflow feasible to implement with SQS?**

Is it possible to read a message from the queue and leave it there? Or do I have to dequeue it and re-enqueue it if not processable by the current consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only SQS it is feasible (but require customised code in the consumer).

Example:
SQS delete message based on the Acknowledgement sent from a consumer. If a consumer sends an acknowledgement, SQS will delete the entry. So, one way to design is:

a) Consume message
b) Check if it is the desired message
c) If it is, then send an ACK to SQS and SQS will delete the entry
d) If the message is not the desired message, do not send and ack and SQS will keep the record

### Other approach:

you can combine SQS with SNS to achieve it.

You can have 3 separate queues for 3 Websocket API e.g. `SQS_A, SQS_B, SQS_C`. And you can have one SNS topic say, `MyTopic`. Then, you can make the Queues subscribed to the SNS topic based on subscription filtering.

Example,

1. `SQS_A` will be subscribed to the SNS topic if the event filter has `user_id 1 and 3` in it.
2. `SQS_B` will be subscribed to the SNS topic if the event filter has `user_id 5` in it.
3. `SQS_C` will be subscribed to the SNS topic if the event filter has `user_id 2` in it.

The event filtering looks like this for SQS_A:

```
{
  "EventType": [
    1,
    3"
  ]
}
```

So... now when the publisher is publishing the message, it will publish the message to the SNS topic along with the event type.

Example:

```
sns.PublishInput{
        Message:  msg,
        TopicArn: topic,
        MessageAttributes: {
            EventType: {
                DataType: "String",
                StringValue: <listOfUserId>
            }
        }
}
```

Now, the SNS will only send this message to the `SQS_A` and not the rest of the SQS. So, only Websocket A will consume the message.

More: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-subscription-filter-policies.html

**NB: This is not a robust, easily extendable, scalable design**

Comment: But... it's not true that it's not feasible with SQS! I read: Amazon SQS doesn't automatically delete a message after retrieving it for you, in case you don't successfully receive the message (for example, if the consumers fail or you lose connectivity). To delete a message, you must send a separate request which acknowledges that you've successfully received and processed the message. Note that you must receive a message before you can delete it.

Comment: Yeah... you're right. But in your way, you have to have customised logic in your consumer i.e. a) consume message b) check if it's the message I want c) if it is, send an ACK to the SQS and SQS will delete the msg d) if it does not, do not send the ACK and SQS will not delete it. --- Arguably, it can be done too. But you're going with customised logic as I said (which necessarily does not mean a bad thing also). So... yeah, you could design it this way too...

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case for Publisher-Subscriber Architecture. To implement this on AWS infra, start with assuming SQS as the subscribers. The message filtration should not come into place while consuming the subscribed message. This is part of Publisher. AWS offers SNS which can act as the Publisher.

Assume the following setup. Use SNS as the publisher. In this, you can do the message filtering (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html). This allows SNS to send messages selectively.
[image]

In your use case,
`[Mesage for user 1/3]` -> SNS -> SQS for A -> `Websocket A only gets messages for user 1/3`
`[Mesage for user 5]` -> SNS -> SQS for B -> `Websocket A only gets messages for user 5`

Please note that SNS topic in both cases remains the same. But the subscriber filters the message and you'll have multiple SQS queues.

Comment: In my case I can't have one queue per user. Can't I just use SNS with filtering, and skip SQS at all?